# Lidar com erros em Next.js e Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

Estou fazendo uma aplicação Next.js que usa Axios para fazer requests. As informações que uso da API estão vindo normalmente mas gostaria de lidar melhor com os erros retornados. Atualmente meu código apenas retorna um erro 404 se o request retornar qualquer tipo de erro, mas sei que podem vir outros erros e assim gostaria de tornar minha aplicação mais dinâmica.

O que tentei até agora foi:

1. Primeiramente eu faço o request pelo Axios e pego o erro que ele retorna se o GET não for bem-sucedido.
2. Depois eu processo as informações se os dados existirem
3. Se não existirem eu retorno `error: true` nas `props` do componente
4. No componente retorno o erro do Next.js se `error` existir

Mas todo esse processo é muito longo e acaba não retornando o erro e a mensagem propriamente ditos. Assim gostaria de saber se há uma forma mais simples de lidar com os erros talvez usando algo nativo do Axios. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço desde já.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {

    const res = await axios.get(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/${query.id}.json?print=pretty`)
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err.response) {
                return err.response
            }
        })
        
    const data = res.data

    if (data) {

        // Processa informações

    } else {
        return {
            props: { data: null, submitted: null, comments: null, error: true }
        }
    }
}

export default function UserPage({ data, submitted, comments, error }) {

    if (!error) {
        return (
            <>
                // Retorna o componente
            </>
        )
    } else {

        return <Error statusCode={404} /> // Erro do Next.js
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Permita-me perguntar: o `await Promise.resolve(promiseData)` é realmente necessário?

Comment: Ele retornaria Promise Pending se não tivesse, certo?

Comment: Não. A propriedade `data` retornada pelo `axios` não é uma promessa. Portanto, utilizar `await` ali é desnecessário. O `Promise.resolve` também não está fazendo nada...

Comment: Então posso remover essa linha do código?

Comment: Sim. Pode utilizar `data` direto do `res.data`. :)

Comment: Ok. Ainda funciona. Obrigado.